# Can a badge be removed after being awarded?

Tags: support

Out of curiosity (not a real problem): I have [a question](https://superuser.com/questions/1502796/how-do-i-activate-windowsxp-now-that-support-has-ended) with 99 votes, now I'm waiting patiently for the 100th vote ;). With the 100th vote a badge will be awarded and I was wondering what happens if the 100th vote gets removed **after** the badge has been awarded. Will the badge will be removed as well? The [help center](https://superuser.com/help/badges/22/great-question) doesn't give any information about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Will the badge will be removed as well?

No for "regular" badges (unless foul play was involved):

> In general, if no foul play caused a badge to be awarded (say, a badge
> for good answer but due to sock-puppet upvotes), even if the
> conditions that caused a badge to be earned are no longer true, the
> badge will remain.
>
> We don't revoke badges, unless there was fraud involved in getting
> them in the first place.
>
> The above is true for "regular" badges - tag badges are a different
> matter.

Source: [Losing a badge in StackOverflow [duplicate]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261259), answer by [Oded](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1583/oded)